# My iPod is disabled, how can I recover?

Tags: ios, restore, ipod

My iPod 4 was disabled for 1657 Mins Yesterday. I put it on the charger to see if it would make a difference the next day and it did. Those mins were gone and all it said was connect to iTunes (but it is still disabled).

I need to reboot my iPod on iTunes but I don't know how. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter your password wrong too often, you either have to wait the time shown on the screen or erase the device with iTunes (or through iCloud, but that probably doesn't apply for you). The exact procedure depends on whether you synced your iPod with your PC before. Apple has a [support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306) explaining the required steps in detail.

PS: If you haven't used iTunes before, you will have to install it on your PC first.